# Why do a[] and *a behave differently?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

I thought `a[]` and `*a` are the same thing because they work like pointers. Yet I encountered something unexpected in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class F {
public:
    bool a[];
    F();
};

F::F() {
    *a = new bool[5];
    a[2] = true;
}

int main() {
    F obj;
    if(obj.a[2])
        cout << '?';
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints `?`, but I don't understand how it works. When:

```
*a = new bool[5];
```

is changed into:

```
a = new bool[5];
```

compiler reports:

```
F:\main.cpp|11|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'bool*' to 'bool [0]'|
```

I found this behaviour weird, so I was playing around with this code. When I changed the type of `a` from `bool` to `int` compiler always reports an error

```
F:\main.cpp|11|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
```

**Why does this work the way it does?**

Comment: `bool a[];` as a member is a compiler extension, not standard C++. Is there a reason you're not using `std::vector`?

Comment: @TartanLlama Maybe he likes his memory leaks ;)

Comment: When u write new, it is creating a pointer to the array of bool on the heap. As a itself is the array, *a is the correct equivalence of pointer of array of bool.

Comment: @TartanLlama I am not that good with STL so I tried using default data types.

Comment: @MarkoDivjak you forgot the destructor freeing your array you alloaded with ``new[]``.

Comment: @MarkoDivjak I'd recommend learning how to use the standard library rather than rolling your own solutions to these problems.

Comment: @SteveDengZishi
`new[]` should return a pointer? I don't understand how could I assign a pointer value to `*a`.

Comment: When `bool a[];` is written like that inside a class/struct declaration, it is not valid C++. Similarly, it is not valid C either (unless as a special case, it is the very last item inside a struct). Why your non-standard code behaves in a certain way when it shouldn't even compile, is anyone's guess. Consult your compiler manual regarding non-standard language extensions.

Comment: @MarkoDivjak: Implicit conversion from pointer to `bool`. Null pointers become `false`, any other pointer is `true`. But the title doesn't make sense really.

Comment: @Lundin That's unnecessarily handwavy. We could rewrite the code to be standards compliant C++ and the same issue would still manifest. Not that the question itself has anything to do with the title.

Comment: @Voo The OP is obviously confused about what `a[]` even means, which is the source of the problem, as the code doesn't make any sense. What is `bool a[]; ... *a = ...` supposed to mean? Assign something to the contents of the array? Since it apparently compiles, it makes me wonder what the person who wrote that compiler extension was smoking.

Comment: @Lundin The compiler extension is presumably intended for exactly the same use case as in C. Not that weird imo - assuming it doesn't compile if you make the class a non-POD or have it as anything but the last member.

Comment: @Voo This code makes just as little sense in C. What would the use-case be in C then? A flexible array member? How exactly would you use a flexible array member that's not located at the end of the struct?

Comment: @Lundin It is located at the end - there is after all only a single member in this class.

Comment: @Voo Then kindly explain to me how this "C code equivalent" works and what's the rationale behind it: `struct { bool a[]; } ... *mystruct.a = malloc(5*sizeof(bool));`. It doesn't even make sense if `a` was a pointer.

Comment: @Lundin That's not how you use variable sized arrays in structures. If you're confused about the fact that the code in this question is wrong, you'll see that I never said anything about that, just that the feature itself as designed by the "compiler person" is valid and makes sense (in the same circumstances where you'd use it in C - not very many). If you're confused why the code compiles, this has nothing to do with any compiler extensions, that's due to an implicit conversions from `T*` to `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought `a[]` and `*a` are the same thing because they work like pointers.

Let's talk about this piece of declaration:

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
int *b = NULL;
```

This is how they land in memory in the executable:

```
   +----+----+----+----+
a: |  1 |  2 |  3 |  5 |        <-- 4 integers
   +----+----+----+----+

   +----------+
b: |   NULL   |                   <-- 1 pointer that points to nowhere
   +----------+
```

As you can see, they **are not** the same thing.

**What happens after `b = new int[4];`?**

The new memory layout of `b` is something like this:

```
   +----------+
b: | 0xacf3de |               <-- 1 pointer that points to a block of 4 integers
   +----------+

Somewhere else in memory (at address 0xacf3de)...

          +----+----+----+----+
0xacf3de: |  ? |  ? |  ? |  ? |         <-- 4 integers
          +----+----+----+----+
```

**But wait, somebody told me that arrays work like pointers...**

No, that's not true. The arrays do not work like pointers.

An array name (`a`, f.e.) can be used as a shortcut for its address in memory (which is, in fact, the address of its first element). The following notations are equivalent:

```
a
&a
&a[0]
```

The value of all of them is the address in memory where the first element of `a` (the `1` in the example above) is stored.

`a[0]` is an `int`, `&a[0]` is an `int *`. This is the complete form. The other two are shortcuts that the language provides in order to make the code easier to read and understand.

**The things are different for pointers.**

`b` is the value stored in the `b` variable (`NULL` or `0xacf3de` in the example above. It is a value of type `int *` -- the address in memory where an `int` is stored. `&b` is the address in memory where (the value of) `b` is stored. Its type is `int **` -- a pointer to a pointer to an `int`; or "the address in memory where is stored the address of an `int`".

**But wait, they can be replaced one for another in some contexts**

Up to some point, yes, a pointer and an array are interchangeable. As you can see above, there is a common data type involved: `int *`. It is the type of `b` (which stores the address of an `int`) and also the type of `&a[0]` (which is also the address of an `int`).

This means that where `b` can be used, `a` (a short of `&a[0]`) can be used instead, and vice-versa.

Also, where `*b` can be used, `*a` can be used instead. It is the short for `*&a[0]` and it means "the value (`*`) stored at the address (`&`) of `a[0]`" and it is, in fact, the same as `a[0]`.

But, where `&b` can be used, `&a` **cannot** be used instead; remember that `&a` is the same as `&a[0]` and its type is `int *` (but the type of `&b` is `int **`).

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
*a = new bool[5];
```

is equivalent to:

```
a[0] = new bool[5];
```

You are not initialiazing your array, but allocating an array of `bool` which is then implicitly converted into `bool` to be assigned to `a[0]`: the value should be `true` since the pointer returned by `new` should be different from `0`. This implicit conversion does not apply with `int`s: that is why you are getting an error when changing the type of `a`.

---

Now, considering this line:

```
a = new bool[5];
```

Here you are trying to assign your dynamically allocated array to `a`, in other words assigning a pointer to an array `bool*` to a static array `bool[0]`: as the compiler says, the types are incompatible. A static array `a[]` can be used as a pointer, e.g. in the following code:

```
int foo(bool* a) { /* ... */ }

bool my_array[5];
foo(my_array);
```

But pointers can not be converted into static arrays as you are trying to do.

Comment: The pointer returned by `new` is always valid and non-null: if the allocation fails, an exception is thrown.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan ...in which case it's self-explanatory ;)

Comment: @Quentin yeah, definitely :)

Comment: Maybe you could be a tad bit more explicit about the question ("Why do a[] and *a behave differently?"). I'd imagine some words about, when they can be used equivalently (function parameters, ...) and how initialization differs.

Answer (score 0):

Type of value returned from  `new Type[x]` is `Type *` i.e pointer of that type

examle:
So Right  syntax is
 `bool a;`

`*a = new bool[x];`

so it is wrong to do like is

`a=new bool[x]` wrong syntax as it is invalid to assign pointer to a normal varibale

[see for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx)